# How are concatenated strings allocated?

Tags: c++, string, memory, concatenation

I was wondering how strings and memory work together.

As far as I'm aware, I know that when a string is created, it puts some array of characters + '\0' into memory. I also know that they're immutable. So for things like concatenation, what happens in memory that allows you to access the same string?

I don't imagine that the string or character you concatenated is put directly after the addresses of the original strings because that might overlap some needed memory.

In C# and other languages, you can say:

`string s = "Hello"` `...` `s = s + '!'`

Would this be creating a new string? One that is pointing to a new location that says "Hello!", leaving the original never to be referenced?

Or is there a default char buffer that strings use that allows for some space in concatenation?

Comment: `std::string` isn't immutable.

Comment: a _string literal_ is immutable.  A array of chars is not immutable, nor is `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `std::string` isn't immutable.

When using the + operator with strings, as in `s + '!'`, a new temporary string is created which contains the result. `s = s + '!'` copies this temporary string back into the original `s`, replacing the original text. This is how immutable strings work in other languages.

When you use += operator or append function, the string is modified and the extra characters are added to the same string object. However, internally a new memory buffer may be allocated if the old one isn't big enough. When reallocating, some extra space is usually requested to allow small future appends without reallocating (more efficient). You can optionally increase the minimum size of the internal buffer with the reserve function. This is more efficient if you know how much data you will append.

Comment: Let's assume we're working with "const char *", if one was initialized with a buffer of say, 10. Changing a character passed that buffer wouldn't be very safe because you're playing with unknown territory. If we wanted to add to that string, the only solution would be to allocate a whole new array of characters, right?

Comment: @Radnyx I'm not sure what you mean, a code example would be better. If you concatenate or append a C-style string (const char *) to std::string, the data is copied from the C-Style string buffer into std::string. After this point, it doesn't matter if const char * remains pointing to valid data.

Comment: @NeilKirk  You are generalizing too much, as the behavior **is** dependent on STL implementation.

Comment: @MarioRossi No my answer is correct for all implementations conforming to current C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks Neil, that sounds like a very reasonable way to handle character buffers and allocation. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @MarioRossi In C++11, there are new overloads to + operator I wasn't aware of involving move constructors. But I am pretty sure the operator still results in a new string allocation at some point, unless an existing string object is explicitly moved as a parameter.

Comment: @NeilKirk Noted in my answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk  I've checked and this is as you say in C++11.  It wasn't the same in C++98 or some previous version.  In certain way (and we have to be generous), my answer is also correct because the OP didn't specify version.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

The behavior for the expression you're questioning is well-defined by the standard and is required for implementations to follow. The relevant sections of the standard are as follows:

**C++11 § 21.4.8.1-11**

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator> 
    basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>
operator+(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
          const charT* rhs);
```

> Returns: `lhs + basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>(rhs)`

This leads to:

**C++11 § 21.4.8.1-3**

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
    basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>
operator+(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
          basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>&& rhs);
```

> Returns: `std::move(rhs.insert(0, lhs))`

and finally...

**C++11 § 21.4.2-22**

```
basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>&
  operator=(basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>&& str) noexcept;
```

> Effects: If *this and str are not the same object, modifies *this as
>   shown in Table 71. [Note: A valid implementation is swap(str). — end
>   note ]

In other words, a temporary is created for the rhs of the `+` operator, that rvalue-reference is then modified using `rhs.insert(0,lhs)`, and finally, the results are sent to the rvalue-reference version of the assignment operator, which can validly perform a move operation.

See the relevant sections of the standard for more info.

---

**C++03x Notes**

It has been requested I provide the same walk-through for C++03x. I'm not positive as to the last(official) rev of the standard, but for reference the following is based on ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E). Use at your own discretion.

A similar walk-through is also wall defined for C++03x, as described below with relevant sections of the standard duly noted.

**C++03x § 21.3.7.1-5**

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
             basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>
operator+(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs, const charT* rhs);
```

> Returns: `lhs + basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>(rhs)`

So like C++11, a temporary is constructed from the *rhs* of the expression. From there...

**C++03x § 21.3.7.1-1**

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
             basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>
operator+(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs, 
          const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
```

> Returns: basic_string(lhs).append(rhs)

Here we differ from C++11. We construct a temporary of the *lhs*, then append the given *rhs* (the temporary from the first step) using the `append()` member function. I'm omitting the const-reference constructor for the temporary of the *lhs* for brevity. This takes us to....

**C++03x § 21.3.5.2-1**

```
basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>&
  append(const basic_string<charT,traits>& str);
```

> Returns: `append(str, 0, npos)`

This forwards the call to the related member function that accepts the starting and stopping indexes from the rhs from which to enumerate. This takes us to...

**C++03x § 21.3.5.2-2..5**
    basic_string&
      append(const basic_string& str, size_type pos, size_type n);

> Requires: pos <= str.size()
>
> Throws: out_of_range if pos > str.size().
>
> Effects: Determines the effective length rlen of the string to append as the smaller of n and str.size() - pos. The function then throws length_error if size() >= npos - rlen. Otherwise, the function replaces the string controlled by *this with a string of length size() + rlen whose first size() elements are a copy of the original string controlled by *this and whose remaining elements are a copy of the initial elements of the string controlled by str beginning at position pos.
>
> Returns: *this.

Essentially this does some sanity checks on the positional parameters, then performs the replacement with concatenated content. And finally, now that are finished rhs of the assignment is complete, we can perform the assignment operation to the target of this whole fiasco, which takes us to...

**C++03x § 21.3.1-16**

```
basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>&
  operator=(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& str);
```

> Effects: If *this and str are not the same object, modifies *this as shown in Table-43
>
> Returns: *this

Table-43 denotes the following required effects.

> `data()` -  points to the first element of an allocated copy of the array whose first element is pointed at by the `str.data()`
>
> `size()` -  `str.size()`
>
> `capacity()` - At least as large as `size()`

My assessment of that is the implementation can do what it wants to achieve those effects (in Table 43; the path of implementation as shown here is still required).

I'm too tired to drive into C++98. I hope this is enough.

Comment: @MarioRossi I don't have a copy of C++ 0x3 in front of me, nor C++ 98. The C++11 standard is old enough now and all the compilers I use for work day-to-day and personal projects are C++11 compliant. It does peak my interest however. I'll do some poking around.

Comment: @MarioRossi Edited. Its late here so I hope I didn't gloss over somewhere in the middle of that. I have officially gained a whole new appreciation for rvalue-references and move-assignment.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That's closer to what I remembered, especially that operations were defined more in terms of external state than implementation.  Yeah, no need to go as far as 98.  It's probably the same or promoting even more implementation freedom.  The idea was to allow vendors to produce implementations that competed against each other.  Theoretically, that was going to promote the adoption of the language (as well as protect investments).  And probably did promote the language.  Don't know the other.

Comment: @MarioRossi LOL. and after all that I peek back up at the question from the OP and see this: `s = s + '!'` Note the *character* being appended; *not* a `const char *` Egads I really need to stop drinking coffee so late in the evening. Either that or *start* drinking **alocohol** earlier in the day.

Answer (score 0):

Up to C++11, it was implementation-dependent.  However, libraries had (and still have) a much better chance of optimizing when you use `+=` than when you use `+` .  The big difference is that C++11 now specifies (and mandates) these optimizations.

The general rule (with past, present, and future specifications of the language and even  similar languages) is:  always prefer

```
s+= "!" ;
```

in place of the example code you used.

The reason is that `string`s are not language primitives.  They are just another "user" type (that happens to come with the compiler, but that's another story).  When you write

```
s = s + "!" ;
```

the `+` method of class `string` is invoked.  However, it is forced to create a new object (maybe sharing some storage with `s`), because you could have used it in this other context:

```
t = s + "!" ;
```

Conversely, the `+=` method can be sure you want to append to the current string, and thus optimize a bit (example:  use available space in an internal buffer).

Comment: What is implementation dependent?

Comment: 1)  string is a class of the STL, not of C++.  2)  The `S` in STL refers to a standard interface, not to a standard implementation.

Comment: std::string is provided by C++ standard and its behavior is well defined. Nobody talks about "the STL" any more.

Comment: Even if we agreed on that, we still have 2).  I.e. several implementations.  Apache, GNU, Rogue Wave, and Microsoft being probably the most important.

Comment: The answers to his questions are not implementation dependent. They are well defined by C++ standard.

Comment: @Neil  As per the very complete analysis made by WhozCraig, this was more or less as I describe until C++11.  I need to grease my C++ gears.  I didn't thought they were going to change that because of the reasons I mention in my comment to WhozCraig.  I'm correcting my answer.